# How to get the sum of two elements from the Spark RDD Iiterable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write a simple program to find the sum of hours-logged and sum of miles-logged by a driver. I have applied groupByKey and the RDD look like this now.

```
(13,CompactBuffer((49,2643), (56,2553), (60,2539), (55,2553), (45,2762), (53,2699), (46,2519), (60,2719), (56,2760), (51,2731), (57,2671), (47,2604), (58,2510), (51,2649), (56,2559), (59,2604), (47,2613), (49,2585), (58,2749), (50,2756), (57,2596), (54,2517), (48,2554), (47,2576), (58,2528), (60,2765), (54,2689), (51,2739), (51,2698), (47,2739), (51,2546), (54,2647), (60,2504), (48,2536), (51,2602), (47,2651), (53,2545), (48,2665), (55,2670), (60,2524), (48,2612), (60,2712), (60,2583), (47,2773), (57,2589), (51,2512), (57,2607), (57,2576), (53,2604), (59,2702), (51,2687), (10,100)))
```

Could you suggest me some useful scala functions to get the sum of the 2 elements? Thanks!!

Comment: Try to use aggregateByKey transformation in place of groupByKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here's one approach using `groupByKey`, `mapValues` and `reduce` to aggregate hours and miles:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (13, (49,2643)),
  (13, (56,2553)),
  (13, (60,2539)),
  (14, (40,1500)),
  (14, (50,2500))
))

rdd.groupByKey.mapValues( _.reduce( (a, x) => (a._1 + x._1, a._2 + x._2) ) )
// res1: Array[(Int, (Int, Int))] = Array((13,(165,7735)), (14,(90,4000)))
```

Or as pointed out by commenters, aggregate using `reduceByKey` directly if you don't need the intermediary result from `groupByKey`:

```
rdd.reduceByKey( (a, x) => (a._1 + x._1, a._2 + x._2) )
```

Comment: You can just use `reduceByKey` : `rdd.reduceByKey{ (a, b) => (a._1+b._1, a._2+b._2) }`

Comment: Thanks @philantrovert.  I just followed what the OP had already applied and neglected to suggest the better alternative.  Answer updated.